# Realtime data aggregation with respect to time slots

Tags: time-series, aggregate

I have a requirement and I am looking if there is already a solution for such a problem.

I have a stream of integer data, let's call it `x`, coming from a source with a timestamp. I need to aggregate max and min value of `x` in the timeslot of `2 minutes`, `5 minutes`, `15 minutes`, etc, and save it in DB.

I thought of aggregating it in memory and save the aggregate result to DB at the end of each time slot. But, if app crash or restart then I will lose these data. Which made me think if there is already a solution for such a problem.

**Edit**: Few more details

Data is a large scale single labelled data like `{label, x, timestamp}`. I don't want to store all the data which I get. I need to save only min and max for each time window.

For example, the following is stream of data.

```
time  label  value
1     A       200
1     A       12 
1     B       23 
2     A       23
2     B       400
3     A       23
3     B       2
4     A       4
4     B       12


Output needed

For the first five minute
A min: 4 max: 200
B min: 2 max: 400

Next five minute
.....
.....
```

Comment: How much data are you talking about in the stream? Small scale vs large scale are solved differently.  Do you have availability requirements?

Comment: @hyprnick Stream of data I get is large scale data. I need to save only the aggregate, no need to save all the data points. I have added more details in the question.

Comment: It really depends on how much data you want to store. Even with storing aggregated data, the cardinality of your “label” column will have an effect. To get a better idea of the scale, how many inserts per second are you thinking for the aggregated rows? Does this need to be available 24/7?

Comment: @hyprnick Cardinality is one for the label. Here is the concrete use case: I have 5000 products, customers are placing a bid to purchase it. I have to store min and max bid for a given time window (1st 5 minutes, 2nd 5 minutes, .... current 5 minutes) etc. Each product may have 1000 bid/second depending on popularity. In this case for each time window, I save 5000 aggregate results, i.e 5000 per 5 minutes.

Comment: Cardinality of 1 would mean there is only a single value for `label`. Cardinality refers to the unique number of elements.  In your example above, you show `A` and `B`.  If those are the only two possible values, your cardinality would be 2.

Comment: In that case cardinality is 1000

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, aggregating in memory does have the potential to lose data if the app crashes or the node it's running on dies abruptly. It also increases the complexity of your code.

In your concrete example, you gave an example of a bidding system.  If you are aggregating the bids, how do you know who has the highest or lowest bid?  Is this system only for analytics purposes or is it powering the bid system itself?

You have a couple options.

You could store the aggregations in a database such as MySQL or Postgres. You would have to ensure that this is an [HA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_availability) setup (e.g. master-slave) to ensure uptime during node failure. The downside to this approach is that your table will start to degrade in performance once it gets in the 5M-10M range. At 5,000 per 5 minutes, you'll accumulate about 1.4M/day.  This could quickly run into scaling issues down the road. I have seen systems that go around this with manual partitions and sharding which adds quite a bit of overhead.  You would also have to handle downsampling the data to save on space.

Another option is to try a time-series database designed for work loads like this, such as [Hyprcubd](https://www.hyprcubd.com). Disclaimer: I'm the founder.  I would not suggest it if it does not fit your use case.  If you need transactions, this would not be a good fit as Hyprcubd does not support transactions. If all you are tracking are `(time, label, bid)`,  this might work. You could even store each raw bid without aggregating `(time, label, bid, user)` which would greatly simplify your code.  Your code would then become stateless.